# What is the simplest way to look up a adjacent value in a structured Numpy array of unique elements?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a structured Numpy array with two columns where the elements of each column are all unique.  For example:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(
    [(1,'a'),(2, 'b'),(3, 'c')], 
    dtype=[('idx', np.int8), ('value', np.unicode_, 16)]
    )
```

I would like to look up a value based on the index.  Ideally, a way to return 'b' where the index is '2', for instance.  This is the best method I have found so far:

```
value = (set(np.where(arr['idx'] == 2, arr['value'], None)) - {None}).pop()
```

To make this less rediculous to implement, I wrapped the logic in a function:

```
def getAdjacentValue(arr, c1, c2, v):
    return (set(np.where(arr[c1] == v, arr[c2], None)) - {None}).pop()
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this without so much hacky code?  It would be ideal, of course, if there was a `np.where` function that operated like this, like `np.where(arr['idx']==2, arr['value'])` where only one value was returned and no "else" value was required.  Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use Pandas instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [300]: arr = np.array( 
     ...:     [(1,'a'),(2, 'b'),(3, 'c')],  
     ...:     dtype=[('idx', np.int8), ('value', np.unicode_, 16)] 
     ...:     )                                                                                              
In [301]: arr                                                                                                
Out[301]: 
array([(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')],
      dtype=[('idx', 'i1'), ('value', '<U16')])
```

It's easy to find the records where the `idx` value is 2:

```
In [303]: arr['idx']==2                                                                                      
Out[303]: array([False,  True, False])
```

This a boolean mask.  We could wrap it in `np.where`, but we can also use it directly:

```
In [304]: arr[arr['idx']==2]                                                                                 
Out[304]: array([(2, 'b')], dtype=[('idx', 'i1'), ('value', '<U16')])
```

and we can extract the `value` part of that record.

```
In [305]: arr[arr['idx']==2]['value']                                                                        
Out[305]: array(['b'], dtype='<U16')
```

You talk about unique elements, but your example doesn't demonstrate any need for any added `set` or `unique` use.  If my answer does not meet your needs, you need to construct a better example.

```
In [306]: np.where(arr['idx']==2)                                                                            
Out[306]: (array([1]),)
In [307]: arr[np.where(arr['idx']==2)]                                                                       
Out[307]: array([(2, 'b')], dtype=[('idx', 'i1'), ('value', '<U16')])
```

Other cases, with no results and with multiple results:

```
In [309]: arr[np.where(arr['idx']==4)]['value']                                                              
Out[309]: array([], dtype='<U16')
In [310]: arr[np.where(arr['idx']>1)]['value']                                                               
Out[310]: array(['b', 'c'], dtype='<U16')
```

Comment: I think you nailed it, thank you.  Returning a row of data given the index is what I'm looking for and much more concise than what I originally wrote.  I don't use Numpy very often and I think my question is proof :) .

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this should do the trick:

```
value = arr[np.where(arr['idx']==2)[0][0]][1]
```

Or in your function

```
def getAdjacentValue(arr, c1, c2, v):
    return arr[np.where(arr[c1]==v)[0][0]][c2]
```

But honestly the way your array is constructed I owuld just use a dictionary instead. You can read more on dictionaries here:

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

```
my_dict = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```

and you can extract the value simply by:

```
value = my_dict[2]
```

Additionally you can print out all your values in the dictionary by

```
print(my_dict.keys())
```

and all the values in your dictionary you can simply obtain by:

```
my_dict.values()
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if numpy is necessary, but if it's not  a dictionary is ideal:

```
arr = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
value = arr[2]
```

In this dictionary you can for example use `numpy.int8` types as keys, if the types are the reason for using numpy.

Comment: You're right, a dictionary would be ideal.  But in this instance, everything comes in and goes out as numpy arrays and I'd rather not convert to a new data type just to look up a value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do this several times, it is best that you sort the array (once) and then use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) on every query:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(
    [(1,'a'),(2, 'b'),(3, 'c')], 
    dtype=[('idx', np.int8), ('value', np.unicode_, 16)]
    )
arr_sorted = np.sort(arr)
value = arr_sorted['value'][np.searchsorted(arr_sorted['idx'], 2)]
```